# DotNet Maui - Button - control the Imagesource size

Tags: maui

How can I resize the image when I use the ContentLayout the put the text below the ImageSource.

```
<HorizontalStackLayout>
    
    <Button MaximumHeightRequest="50"
            Text="Open"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            ImageSource="file_open.png"
            ContentLayout="left,50" />
    <Button Text="Open file test"
            ContentLayout="Top,0"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            ImageSource="file_open.png"
            Command="{Binding DivideBy2Command}" />
    <ImageButton x:Name="Toto"
            MaximumHeightRequest="50"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            Source="file_open.png"
            Command="{Binding DivideBy2Command}" />
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

[image]

Per Feedback from ToolmakerSteve and Alexandar May - MSFT Stackoverflow users and also playing with Padding  I was able get what I need. Here the updated code.

```
<HorizontalStackLayout>
    <Button Text="Open"
            HeightRequest="50"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            ImageSource="file_open.png"
            ContentLayout="left, 0"
            />
    <Button 
        VerticalOptions="Start"
        Text="Open File"
        FontSize="10"
        ImageSource="file_open.png"
        ContentLayout="Top,-10"
        Padding="2,-10,2,2"
        HeightRequest="50"
        WidthRequest="50"
        />
    <ImageButton 
        VerticalOptions="Start"
        Source="file_open.png"
        MaximumHeightRequest="50"  
        />
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

Here the Output

[image]

Comment: First, I see you use `MaximumHeightRequest` in third image button. That is almost never what you want; try `HeightRequest` instead. What happens if you put `HeightRequest` on the Open file test button?

Comment: HeightRequest set the height of the button but the image is not scaledown to fit in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting the `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` of the **Button** like below:

```
    <HorizontalStackLayout >

        <Button 
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            MaximumHeightRequest="50"
            Text="Open"
            ImageSource="file_open.png"
            ContentLayout="left, 50"
            />

        <Button 
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            Text="Open file test"
            FontSize="10"
            ImageSource="file_open.png"
            Command="{Binding DivideBy2Command}"
            ContentLayout="Top,0"
            
            HeightRequest="100"
            WidthRequest="100"
            />

        <ImageButton 
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            x:Name="Toto"
            Source="file_open.png"
            MaximumHeightRequest="50"
            Command="{Binding DivideBy2Command}"    
            />

    </HorizontalStackLayout>
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. Setting height and width request to 100 scale the image and text almost perfectly but only upper half of the letter P is shown. Is there a way to fix that.

Comment: You can set `ContentLayout="Top,-5"` to set the text to the upper place. If it still doesn't work, please attach the image to your post so I can help you test it.

Comment: Thank for the reply Alexandar May. Did update my post by adding  new content below the first post issue. Let me know it is Ok to do that way.

Comment: Done. Merci Beaucoup !

Comment: Is this a bug that was fixed in an update? Somehow this does not work for me. The icon stays large, only the button height is being set.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace all "\" with "/" in the image path, this solved the problem at least for me.